# Python regex for deleting a given list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code:

```
import re

pattern = r"(?s)FUNCTION [A-Z]{4,6}(.*?)\b\w*(?<!,)END\b"
regex = re.compile(pattern)

with open('functions.f', 'r') as input_file:
    with open('stripped.f', 'w') as output_file:
        result = regex.sub('', input_file.read())
        output_file.write(result)
```

It looks for functions with name length of 4 to 6 characters and deletes them. I would like to be able to delete only specific functions using a list of names so that if there are

```
FUNCTION ABCD
END
FUNCTION EFGHI
END
FUNCTION JKLM
,END
FUNCTION NOPQRS
END
```

and the given list of functions to be removed is `[EFGHI,NOPQRS]`, only the corresponding functions are removed and only

```
FUNCTION ABCD
END
FUNCTION JKLM
,END
```

remain in the output file.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There's no point in using `re.MULTILINE` if the regexp doesn't have `^` or `$`.

Comment: `(?s)` is the same as `re.DOTALL`

Comment: You might exclude what to match `\b(?!ABCD|JKLM)\b[A-Z]{4,6}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[A-Z]{4,6}` with the list of specific function names separated by `|`. Put this in a group to match it as a sub-unit in the regexp.

```
funcs = ['EFGHI','NOPQRS']
pattern = rf"(?s)FUNCTION ({'|'.join(funcs)}).*?\b\w*(?<!,)END\b"
```